# I was trying to make a simple doubly linked list with operations Insert, Delete and Display and

Tags: c

The insert seems to go smoothly but the display only shows the head element only. I wanted to do this on my own and tried to use the logic. I am confused whether the fault lies in the Insert function or the Display.
I am not really that great at programming and just started learning C++.Thank you for your help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *prev;
    struct node *next;
};
struct node *head = NULL;

void insert(struct node **head)
{


    struct node *newnode = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    newnode->next = NULL;
    newnode->prev = NULL;
    if ((*head) == NULL)
    {
        int x;
        printf("\nEnter the value of the starting node :");
        scanf("%d", &x);
        newnode->data = x;
        
        (*head) = newnode;
    }
    else
    {

        int pos, x;

        printf("\nEnter the pos ");

        scanf("%d", &pos);

        if (pos == 0)
        {
            newnode->next = (*head);
            newnode->prev = NULL;
            (*head)->prev = newnode;
            (*head) = newnode;
            printf("\nEnter data in %d pos : ", pos);
            scanf("%d", &x);
            newnode->data = x;
        }

        else
        {
            struct node *temp;
            
            struct node *ptr = (*head);

            
            while(ptr->next!=NULL)
             { 
              for (int i = 0; i < pos - 1; i++)
              
                { ptr = ptr->next;}
                
             }
            if (ptr->next == NULL)
            {

                newnode->prev = ptr;
                newnode->next = NULL;
                printf("\nEnter data in %d pos : ", pos);
                scanf("%d", &x);
                newnode->data = x;
            }
            else
            {

                printf("\nEnter data in %d pos : ", pos);
                scanf("%d", &x);
                newnode->data = x;

                temp = ptr->next;
                newnode->prev = ptr;
                newnode->next = temp;
                ptr->next = newnode;
                temp->prev = newnode;
            }
        }
    }
}

void delete (struct node **head)
{
    struct node *ptr;
    ptr = (*head);
    if ((*head) == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nUnderflow\n");
    }
    else
    {

        int pos;
        printf("\nEnter the pos ");
        scanf("%d", &pos);
        struct node *temp;
        for (int i = 0; i < pos; i++)
        {
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
        temp = ptr->next;
        temp->prev = ptr->prev;
        ptr->next = NULL;
        ptr->prev = NULL;
    }
}

void display(struct node **head)
{
    struct node *ptr = (*head);
    if (ptr != NULL)
    {
       printf(" %d ",ptr->data);
    }
    else
        {
            printf("\nUnderflow OR empty\n");
        }


}




int main()
    {
        

        while (1)
        {
            int x;
            printf("\n1.Insert\n2.Delete\n3.Display\n4.Exit\n\nChoose option :\n");
            scanf("%d", &x);
            switch (x)
            {
            case 1:
            {
                insert(&head);
                break;
            }
            case 2:
            {
                delete (&head);
                break;
            }
            case 3:
            {
                display(&head);
                break;
            }
            default:
            {
                printf("\nWrong operation.Select again :");
                continue;
            }
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

The display was supposed to show the list like
a-> b -> c......

Comment: Can you give an example input, output of your current program, and your expected output?

Comment: You will need a loop (or recursion) in `display` to show the entire list. Right now it only displays `head`.

Comment: @m3ow suppose I enter the first element which is automatically given to the head node or 0th position as 0 and then I give the next position to enter the element as 1 and insert 1 as the data too..and I continue doing this serially. The input is basically 0->1->2->3.... and the output i.e the display should have been the same. nut it shows only 0

Comment: @user18918606 Note that in your `insert` function, in the `if (ptr->next == NULL)` block you fail to set `ptr->next = newnode;`

Comment: Also, the `while/for` loop should just be a `for` loop: `for (int i = 0; i < pos - 1 && ptr->next; i++) ptr = ptr->next;`

Answer (score 0):

In the display function you should take the next node and print that too

```
// head->next1->next2->NULL
struct node *ptr = (*head);
while (ptr != NULL) {
    printf("%d->", ptr->data);
    ptr = ptr->next;
}
printf("NULL");
```

Comment: I tried doing this and the output still remains the same. I believe something is wrong with my insert function but I can't seem to point out where exactly. I have been going through the logic of my code for few hours now and can't seem to find anything wrong(Even used pen and paper to follow through).